# Accessing its own object properties before function returns

Tags: javascript, reactivex

In the below code, the anonymous function run by the `forEach` loop is able to call `subscription.dispose()` on its first run-through, before the `buttonClicks.forEach(..)` has returned the subscription object to the `subscription` variable.

How can `forEach(..)` have access to an object it returns, before `forEach` has finished running at least once?

```
function(button) {
    var buttonClicks = Observable.fromEvent(button, "click");

    // In the case of an Observable, forEach returns a subscription object.
    var subscription =
        buttonClicks.
            forEach(function(clickEvent) {
                alert("Button was clicked. Stopping Traversal.");

                // Stop traversing the button clicks
                subscription.dispose();
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `subscription` is already declared.

It will be initialized after `forEach` returns, before that, it is `undefined`.

So the click handler can refer to the variable. What it cannot do is actually call `dispose`, for that it needs that variable to hold a value (but this won't happen until someone clicks, and by then the `forEach` has long returned and the variable assigned).

Note that `Observable#forEach` does not immediately run the function you pass it (unlike, say, `Array#forEach`). The function is run every time the observable emits a value (here: a click has happened).

Also note that you could later assign `subscription` to something else, and it will call `dispose` on that. It is not really tied to the object returned by `forEach`. The click handler will continue to refer to the *variable*, not to the *value* of the variable at the time it was created.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you. So you mean that when the JS engine first parses the code, the buttonClicks collection is empty. Thus `subscription` is immediately defined? But, as you say, it is initialized after `forEach()` returns. And it tries to call it inside itself, before it has finished returning. What am I missing here? Thanks again

Comment: `buttonClicks` is not a collection. It is an Observable. It does not contain anything. It emits events (that `forEach` can consume).

Comment: `forEach` creates a "subscription". As long as that subscription is alive, your handler function will keep getting called every time the observable emits this event. The `subscription` object that is returned from `forEach` (immeditately) provides a way for you to cancel this process.

Comment: I know. I just called it a collection because in reality it is similar to an Array, except it is asynchronous, can complete (unlike an Event), and can be traversed with forEach(). The confusing part is how the handler can run dispose() on the subscription object, before the forEach had finished its first cycle.

Comment: Again: `forEach` returns immediately (with `subscription`). It *does not* run your event handler right now. That gets run once for every event emitted (every click) until you cancel the subscription.

Comment: `forEach` does not have "cycles". It just establishes the subscription.

Comment: Got it. It is due to its asynchronous nature. The Observable is empty at first (no emitted values), so the forEach does not run the handler at its first cycle. It is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: Just re your point about cycles. `forEach` loops through each element in the Observable "collection" and runs the handler on each element. Just like it would do with an Array. The Observable is not exactly an asynchronous Array per se, but it behaves that way. Thus, if the Observable is empty (i.e. no values have been emitted), forEach will loop 0 times. When a value is added to the Observable (i.e when the underlying data producer, a click Event in this case, emits a value), forEach runs as soon as the call stack has an opening (as it is run in a separate thread by the browser's webapi).

Comment: Yes, but none of these "cycles" run immediately. `Observable#forEach` returns control to its caller right away, before having called the handler even once. `Array#forEach` calls the handler once for every array element before returning control to the caller. I feel that distinction is the core part of the answer to your question. If you had the same code with `Array#forEach` you would indeed get a "cannot call dispose() on undefined".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time here, Thilo. I see what you are saying. Just to be clear, the reason forEach() does not run right away, is because the Observable sequence is empty. It's like calling forEach on an empty array. As soon as the data producer that the Observable was built on produces a value, the handler runs.

Comment: Continuing the nit-picking, but that is not true either. Even if the `Observable` was "full" (I suppose such a thing could be constructed for unit testing for example), the callback will always run asynchronously. Just like a `setTimeout(0)` also returns before the handler gets called. The reason the handlers are not run right away, is NOT because their trigger has not yet been pulled. It is because the call to install them only does just that. The actual execution is done asynchronously.

Comment: That's actually very interesting. I was not aware that asynchronous calls that fired immediately (i.e. at first execution) did not run straight away. I will read up on it. Thanks